# How to change lower case to upper case in Tcl?

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to regsub all lower case letters to upper case in a file using character classes:

```
 regsub -all { [:lower:] } $f { [:upper:] } f
```

but it doesn't do the substitution.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the language? nhahtdh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just read the file into a string and use [string toupper](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M51). Then write it back out to a file.

```
set fp [open "somefile" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp

set file_data [string toupper $file_data]

set fp [open "somefile" "w"]
puts -nonewline $fp $file_data
close $fp
```

Comment: +1. With [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc) we can write: `package require fileutil; fileutil::writeFile somefile [string toupper [fileutil::cat somefile]]`

Comment: thanks @Brian Fenton, this is helpful. However, is there a way to do that with a regsub command?

Comment: I don't know an easy way to do it with a regsub. According to this http://wiki.tcl.tk/9384 it should be possible with \l if you grab the PCRE library.

Answer (score 2):

yes, above will work like charm.

```
set f [string toupper $f]
```

**f** is some list or string. If you want file operations, as usual read from file and write .

Although if you just want to use regsub, give this a try

```
set f "this is a line"

regsub -all {.*} $f {[string toupper {&}]} f

set f [subst -nobackslashes -novariables $f]
```

now your contents in **f** is uppercased.

note: it looks like long way but useful when selecting just particular text to be upper or lowercased

Thanks,